# Add object to BindingList<object>, re-sort and make comboBox update to reflect change

Tags: c#, list, sorting, combobox, bindinglist

I've got a basic Person class defined like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}
```

Now I'm creating a list of people like this:

```
private List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Person("John Smith", 21));
people.Add(new Person("Bob Jones", 30));
people.Add(new Person("Mike Williams", 35));
```

Once my list has been populated, I want to sort it by name like this:

```
// make sure that the list of people is sorted before assigning to bindingList
people.Sort((person1, person2) => person1.Name.CompareTo(person2.Name));
```

Next, I'm creating a BindingList which I will use as the datasource for a combobox like this:

```
private BindingList<Person> bindingList = new BindingList<Person>(people);

comboBoxPeople.DataSource = bindingList;
comboBoxPeople.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBoxPeople.ValueMember = "Name";
```

So far, this much is working ok.  But now I have a couple of problems that I can't seem to get fixed.  First, I need to be able to add Person objects and have the list remain sorted.  Right now, I can add a new Person object to the bindingList (via `bindingList.Add(newPerson)`) and it will show up in the comboBox, albeit at the bottom (i.e., not sorted).  How can I re-sort the bindingList once I've added something to it so that it appears sorted in the comboBox?

Comment: did you try just recall Sort after you add a new element?

Comment: The original .Sort() was on the List<Person> variable *before* it gets assigned to the bindingList.  At the point when I need to add a new Person object, it gets added directly to the bindingList (which apparently doesn't have a .Sort() method) so calling .Sort() on the original List<Person> variable again won't help.  From what I gather, I'll need to implement some kind of sortable bindingList for this to work but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think honestly you don't need special list for this. Just use what you have in your hands, don't reinvent a wheel in other words.

Here is similiar question to yours and solution:

[BindingList<T>.Sort() to behave like a List<T>.Sort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063917/bindinglistt-sort-to-behave-like-a-listt-sort)