# How to control sort order in ListBox and BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, generic-list

So I have a little group manager that consists of a pair of ListBoxes, 2 BindingLists and custom class. Abstract looks like this

```
class MyClass
{
public int ItemId;
public string Name;
public string Other;
...
}
...
BindingList<MYClass> allItems = new BindingList<MyClass>();
BindingList<MyClass> selectedItems = new BindingList<MyClass>();
...
ListBox1.Datasource = allItems;
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
ListBox1.ValueMember = "ItemId:;
...
ListBox2.DataSource = selectedItems;
ListBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
ListBox2.ValueMember = "ItemId";
...
private void MoveItem(MyObject item, BindingList<MyClass> fromList, BindingList<MyClass> toList)
{
toList.Add(item);
fromList.Delete(item);
}
...
```

Everything works well and issue is purely cosmetic. As items are moved between lists they assume new position in respective list thus new position in the ListBox is assumed at the end of the ListBox. That may be confusing to the user. When I enable Sorted parameter on ListBoxes, the display order is correct but wrong objects are moved. So my question is - how do I order items by ItemId so they maintain their positions consistent in both the BindingList and respective ListBox.

Comment: Looks like you need to sort the `BindingList toList`. This seems to be done be repopulating it from a sorted list or array. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063917/bindinglistt-sort-to-behave-like-a-listt-sort) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8a51767-8c13-42fd-b1ea-4a377126c7ee/how-to-call-orderby-on-a-bindinglist-properly)