# How to sort DataGridView when bound to a binding source that is linked to an EF4 Entity

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sorting, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that is linked to a `BindingSource`.

My `BindingSource` is linked to an `IQueryable` list of entities:

```
    public void BindTo(IQueryable elements)
    {
        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = elements;

        bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = source;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;

    }
```

I am wanting my users to be able to click on the grid headers to sort the data - struggling to get this to work.  Is it possible? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Note: DataGridView seems to be WindowsForms, not WPF. Just for the people that also hoped to find a solution for their WPF DataGrid sorting issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently struggled with this same issue; it seems that the IQueryable interface doesn't provide enough information for the DataViewGrid to know how to sort the data automatically; so you have to either repackage your collection from the Entity source using something it can use or do what I did and handle the sorting functionality manually:

```
      private void myDataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
  {
     DataGridViewColumn column = myDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];

     _isSortAscending = (_sortColumn == null || _isSortAscending == false);

     string direction = _isSortAscending ? "ASC" : "DESC";

     myBindingSource.DataSource = _context.MyEntities.OrderBy(
        string.Format("it.{0} {1}", column.DataPropertyName, direction)).ToList();

     if (_sortColumn != null) _sortColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
     column.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = _isSortAscending ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
     _sortColumn = column;
  }
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a way to do this while allowing updates? If you use ToList(), you will only be able to write to the temporary list, and if you don't use ToList, the DataGridView seems to disable adding records if it is bound to an IOrderedEnumerable...

Comment: I realized I needed to call ObjectQuery.OrderBy, and not IEnumerable.OrderBy to maintain updatable binding.

Answer (score 1):

**VB.NET**

If you are using a bindingsource with linq syntax you can sort your data like this

In this case When loading a bindningsource associated with a datagridview from entity framwork objects "NCFile" with having a foreign column to a list of "NCFilePartSet "

```
bsFileSections.DataSource = From ncfps In NCFile.NCFilePartSet Order By ncfps.Sort Select ncfps
```

or like this

```
bsFileSections.DataSource = NCFile.NCFilePartSet.OrderBy(Function(ncfps) ncfps.Sort)
```

where "Sort" is a column in NCFilePartSet

Updates on entities continue working and reflects back to the database

Comment: The OP wants to "[let] my users ... click on the grid headers to sort the data." Your answer works if you hardcode the sorting column, but how do you handle databinding when the user wants to change the sort column and not lose any data that she/he's already edited/added? I think that's the real challenge here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it **is** possible to easily have a sortable DGV when bound to EF data. Use the `BindingListView` from the [BLW library](http://blw.sourceforge.net/) (also, check out [How do I implement automatic sorting of DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770857/how-do-i-implement-automatic-sorting-of-datagridview)).

```
public void BindTo(IQueryable elements)
{
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
    source.DataSource = new BindingListView(elements.ToList());

    bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = source;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = source;

}
```

In my tests, even when `.ToList()` was called within the constructor (as above), changes were propagated to the DB, which surprised me.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet works very well, and fast enough for most purposes...

```
int iColNumber = 3; //e.g., sorting on the 3rd column of the DGV

MyBindingSource.DataSource = MyBindingList.OrderByDescending(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(MyDataGridView.Columns[iColNumber].Name).GetValue(o));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to dynamically convert entities into data table. There is a method

```
 public static DataTable GetTableFromList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            dt.Columns.Add(property.Name, property.PropertyType);

        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                newRow[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item);
            }
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

After conversion pass table into bindingsource

```
source.DataSource = GetTableFromList<T>(elements);
```

Be aware of property types that cannot be converted into a column types.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you.

```
internal class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{   
    public SortOrder MySortOrder { get; set; }
    protected override void OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource MyBindingSource = (BindingSource)base.DataSource;
        DataTable MyDataTable = (DataTable)MyBindingSource.DataSource;
        switch (MySortOrder)
        {
            case SortOrder.None:
                MyDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = base.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name + " ASC";
                MyDataTable = MyDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
                MyBindingSource.DataSource = MyDataTable;
                MySortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending;
                break;

            case SortOrder.Ascending:
                MyDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = base.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name + " DESC";
                MyDataTable = MyDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
                MyBindingSource.DataSource = MyDataTable;
                MySortOrder = SortOrder.Descending;
                break;

            case SortOrder.Descending:
                MyDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = Properties.Settings.Default.OderDataGridView; //SqlOriginOrder
                MyDataTable = MyDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
                MyBindingSource.DataSource = MyDataTable;
                MySortOrder = SortOrder.None;
                break;
        }
        base.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = MySortOrder; //mini arrow 
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this doesn't help. DataTable is something entirely different than `IQueryable`. (And, by the way, you mixed up the cases).

Comment: Sure that DataTable must remain with its DatagridView: software maintenance requires. Should I specify it?

Comment: As long as you're talking about a DataTable this has nothing to with the question.

Comment: Difficult awakening certainly, in France they are called 'Ronchons'. However, you are right; my object has nothing to do with this section. Erase it or move it!