# Datagrid Sorting (Still) Not Working with Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, wpfdatagrid

I'm having trouble with an application I'm writing in VS2010.  I need to display databound data on a Datagrid and allow the user to sort its contents.

This is my situation:

1. I've built a very simple SQL database with 1 table named "Question".  The table has 2 columns, "id_Question" and "QuestionText".
2. I created an Entity model from this database.
3. Under "Data Sources", I've dragged and dropped the "Question" Entity as a Datagrid onto my WPF window.  When run, the Datagrid populates normally with whatever is in the database.  Great.
4. I've set the "CanUserSortColumns" and "CanUserSort" properties of the DataGrid and DataGrid columns to True.  When the column header is clicked, nothing happens, nothing sorts.

Here is the XAML snippet:

```
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              EnableRowVirtualization="True" Height="200" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              Margin="871,126,0,0" Name="questionsDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400"
              CanUserSortColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="id_QuestionColumn1" Header="id Question" Width="SizeToHeader">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=id_Question}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="questionTextColumn1" 
                                Binding="{Binding Path=QuestionText}" Header="Question Text" Width="300"
                                CanUserSort="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I have read the following among many other related articles / questions on Stack Overflow and other sites:

- [Entity Framework 4.0 Databinding with sorting not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702434/entity-framework-4-0-databinding-with-sorting-not-working)
- [How to sort DataGridView when bound to a binding source that is linked to an EF4 Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463505/how-to-sort-datagridview-when-bound-to-a-binding-source-that-is-linked-to-an-ef4)

Each has provided useful insights but I haven't been able to get it to work for my problem.  What do I need to write in the code behind file to get this to work properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your template column not sorting or ANY column is not sorting?

If its issue with template column thenn ...

Set

```
 DataGridTemplateColumn.SortMemberPath="SomeSortableProperty"
 DataGridTemplateColumn.SortDirection="Ascending"
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response but still no luck with the above suggestion.  No columns are sorting whatsoever.  I gather from other posts that I need to create an CollectionViewSource.  I don't know if this is true or not but nothing has worked so far.  Any other thoughts?  Thanks again.

Comment: ohk! Then it should be a entity framework issue. Yes, collectionview source should help. But then you will have to add sort descriptions to it to sort.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and spent a lot of time searching. In the end, the solution was VERY simple:

```
<Window.Resources>

  <CollectionViewSource x:Key="milestonesViewSource" CollectionViewType="ListCollectionView"/>

</Window.Resources>



<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource milestonesViewSource}">

  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">

     <DataGrid.Columns>

       <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="milestoneIdColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=MilestoneId}" Header="Milestone Id"/>

     </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

The problem is the CollectionViewSource, which creates by default a BindingListCollectionView, which implements IBindingList which does not support sorting !

But CollectionViewSource has the property CollectionViewType which allows changing the view type to ListCollectionView, which allows sorting. That's all.

I just fixed it today in my code, so I don't know yet what are the side effects. Presently, everything seems to work fine.