# use filter of bindingSource with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, bindingsource

**I working on a C# win-form app.**

in my form i have Data-Grid-View that bind with a Binding-Source and Binding-Source Data-source is a table of entity-framework.

when i use entity framework i cant use filter of the binding-source and the sort by columns of data-grid-view but when i don't use entity framework i can use them.
how can i use them with entity-framework?

my code when form loads is

```
contex = new myEntity();
myBindingSource.DataSource = contex.myTable;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort DataGridView when bound to a binding source that is linked to an EF4 Entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463505/how-to-sort-datagridview-when-bound-to-a-binding-source-that-is-linked-to-an-ef4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every BindingSource has a property **[SupportsFiltering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.supportsfiltering.aspx)** (and **[SupportsSorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.supportssorting.aspx)**). In case you set an **entitySet as DataSource** these two properties are automatically set to **false**! So there are some possible solutions. Either you provide an extension method to your `IEnumberable<T>` as shown [here](http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=474) or you choose to filter/sort using `Linq2Entities`.

Snippet for **Linq2Entities** could be:

```
myEntity context = new myEntity();
myBindingSource.DataSource = (from m in context.myTable
                              where m.PROPERTY MEETS CONDITION
                              select m).ToList<TYPE>();
```

Snippet for **extension method**:

```
// extension method
public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, bool> filterParam) {
        return list.Where(filterParam);
}

// filtering example
context.myTable.Filter(x => x.ItemName.StartsWith("Test"))
```

Furthermore this subject has been discussed many times before, even here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/filtering-collections-in-c-sharp).

Comment: editet and updated answer. @calling saveChanges on bindingSourceChange - sry I don't understand this comment. What exactly do you mean with this, perhaps you could update your question according to this detail - thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You tagged Entity framework, but you didn't show your model.  Assuming that MyEntity is your ObjectContext or DBContext you could bind to the [local property](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/09/08/data-binding-with-dbcontext.aspx) of the DbSet which is an observable collection that supports sorting.

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = contex.myTable.Local;
```