# Custom sorting with binding source in compact framework?

Tags: c#, datagrid, windows-mobile, compact-framework

This is how I'm currently doing sorts:

```
 BindingSource bs = ( BindingSource )m_dataGrid.DataSource;
bs.Sort = "SortingRow" + " DESC";
```

What I'd like to have is a custom method or something I cna use to sort, something like:

```
bool GreaterThan(object a, object b)
{
(...)//my own code to determine return value
}
```

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: have a look at his link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463505/how-to-sort-datagridview-when-bound-to-a-binding-source-that-is-linked-to-an-ef4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do it.

The DataSource object can generally be cast back to a DataTable, DataView, or whatever it was in the first place.

Not knowing your project, I'll use a DataTable.

When the data is added, cast it back to the DataTable.

```
private void AddData(object data) {
  // data would be what you would normally fill to the m_dataGrid.DataSource
  DataTable table = m_dataGrid.DataSource as DataTable;
  if (table == null) {
    DataView view = m_dataGrid.DataSource as DataView;
    if (view != null) {
      table = view.Table;
    }
  }
  if (table != null) {
    Sort(table);
  }
}
```

The way `AddData` looks is irrelevant because you just want a way to pass your known data to the `Sort` routine.

Your `Sort` routine would need to be something you write. It changes the raw data back to your structured data type, shown here as some generic `MyStuff` class:

```
private void Sort(DataTable table) {
  List<MyStuff> list = new List<MyStuff>(table.Rows.Count);
  for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) {
    string valueA = table.Rows[MyStuff.A_INDEX].ToString();
    int itemB = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[MyStuff.B_INDEX]);
    list.Add(new MyStuff() { ValueA = valueA, ItemB = itemB });
  }
  list.Sort();
  m_dataGrid.DataSource = list;
}
```

For the `list.Sort()` to work, you would need to implement the `IComparable` and `IEquatable` interfaces in your `MyStuff` class.

Crappy generic example to give you an idea:

```
class MyStuff : IComparable<MyStuff>, IEquatable<MyStuff> {

  public const int A_INDEX = 0;
  public const int B_INDEX = 0;

  public MyStuff() {
    ValueA = null;
    ItemB = 0;
  }

  public string ValueA { get; set; }

  public int ItemB { get; set; }

  #region IComparable<MyStuff> Members

  public int CompareTo(MyStuff other) {
    if (other != null) {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ValueA) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(other.ValueA)) {
        int compare = ValueA.CompareTo(other.ValueA);
        if (compare == 0) {
          compare = ItemB.CompareTo(other.ItemB); // no null test for this
        }
        return compare;
      } else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(other.ValueA)) {
        return -1;
      }
    }
    return 1;
  }

  #endregion

  #region IEquatable<MyStuff> Members

  public bool Equals(MyStuff other) {
    int compare = CompareTo(other);
    return (compare == 0);
  }

  #endregion

}
```

I hope that helps.

I can't really spend more time on this, though, because I've got a deadline today.

~Joe