# How to sort data from DataGridView with automatically generated columns from BindingList?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that receives a `BindingList`

```
dataGrid.DataSource = new BindingList<Value>(ValueList);
```

After it I try to set the `SortMode`

```
dataGrid.Columns.OfType<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList()
    .ForEach(c =>
    {
        c.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
    });
```

The breakpoint does stop on it, but my `DataGridView` is not sortable... I try to click on the headers and nothing happens.

These columns are auto generated, what can I do to be able to sort the data?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770857/how-do-i-implement-automatic-sorting-of-datagridview) out

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you need to make a custom binding list that implements the necessary sorting functions so that the DataGridView knows how to sort each column.

This post provides good information on getting sorting working:

http://xiaonanstechblog.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-enable-column-sorting-on.html

If you want to both filter and sort, you may want to do a custom implementation of the IBindingListView interface:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglistview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When **DataGridView** binds to the **DataSource** (*DataView, BindingSource, Table, DataSet+"tablename"*) in all cases it refere to the **DataView**. Get reference to this DataView and set **Sort** (and **Filter**) as you wish:

```
DataView dv = null;
CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)(dgv.BindingContext[dgv.DataSource, dgv.DataMember]);

if (cm.List is BindingSource)
{
    // In case of BindingSource it may be chain of BindingSources+relations
    BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)cm.List;
    while (bs.List is BindingSource)
    { bs = bs.List as BindingSource; }

    if (bs.List is DataView)
    { dv = bs.List as DataView; }
}
else if (cm.List is DataView)
{
    // dgv bind to the DataView, Table or DataSet+"tablename"
    dv = cm.List as DataView;
}

if (dv != null)
{
    dv.Sort = "somedate desc, firstname";
    // dv.Filter = "lastname = 'Smith' OR lastname = 'Doe'";

    //  You can Set the Glyphs something like this:
    int somedateColIdx = 5;    // somedate
    int firstnameColIdx = 3;   // firstname
    dgv.Columns[somedateColIdx].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending;
    dgv.Columns[firstnameColIdx].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
}
```

Note: **Column names used in Sort and Filter correspond to the column names in DataTable**,
Column names in DataGridView are the names of controls used to display cells in dgv.
You can get column name used in DataView like this:

```
string colName = dgv.Columns[colIdx].DataPropertyName
```

Depends of how do you want to track sorted columns (colSequence, colName, asc/desc, dgvColIdx) you may decide how to build Sort and Filter expression and set the SortGlyph in dgv (I made hardcode for simplicity).