# How to Sort WinForms DataGridView bound to EF EntityCollection<T>

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4, datagridview, entitycollection

I'm trying to bind a WinForms DataGridView to an `EntityCollection<T>` from an EntityFramework4 object.  The trouble is, I can't figure out how to get it to sort (automatically).

All I'm doing is setting the BindingSource's DataSource property to the entity's collection.

`MyBindingSource.DataSource = CurrentItem.InvoiceNotes;`

I really hope there's a simple configuration I can add to this to get it to work; I really don't want to have to wrap my EF Collection in a new BindingList container.

Comment: Does `EntityCollection<T>` inherit IListSource, or BindingList<T>? If not, then you should write an AutoSort routine called by the DataSource.Changed event. There are tons of sorting routines available on the Googlenet...   :)

Comment: It does support IListSource, but not BindingList<T>.  Is there something I can do to enable sorting since it implements IListSource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To support sorting, the source needs to implement `IBindingList` with sorting enabled. Annoyingly, AFAIK the only inbuilt type with this is `DataView`.

All is not lost, though; your best option is to create a `BindingList<T>` of your data - or rather, one of the many `BindingList<T>` subclasses available as examples on the internet. `BindingList<T>` gets you 90% of the way there - it just needs about 3 (IIRC) additional methods implementing to get basic (one-column) sorting support.

Dinesh Chandnani wrote a series of articles back in 2005 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dchandnani/archive/2005/03.aspx) that do a good job of explaining binding via a BindingSource. It was written before EF, but it provides some good background information. Here's one tidbit:

> Of course you can bind the DataGridView to the DataTable directly and
>   bypass the BindingSource, but BindingSource has certain advantages:
>
> - It exposes properties to Sort the list, Filter the list, etc. which would other wise be a pain to do. (i.e. if you bind the
>     DataGridView to the DataTable directly then to Sort the DataTable you
>     need to know that DataTable is an IListSource which knows the
>     underlying list which is a DataView and a DataView can be sorted,
>     filtered, etc.).
> - If you have to set up master/child views then BindingSource does a great job of doing this (more details in my previous post)
> - Changes to the DataTable is hidden (also in my previous post)

Comment: annoyingly indeed.  I already had a BindingList<T> implementation, but this grid was supposed to support adding and removing items, so I wanted to bing right to the EntityCollection.  Oh well, I just have to add new items to the EntityCollection and also my BindingList; I've had to do worse things.

Comment: I typically create an internal BindingList<T> accessible through a public getter. Note: I don't typically use editable datagrids.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Marc-Gravell's answer, there is [a library that makes it easy to get sortable DGVs for any list](http://blw.sourceforge.net/), so you can use it and just call `.ToList()` on EF collections, IQueryables, IEnumerables, etc. Now the question is, if you use `.ToList()` and sort, will databinding still work? In all of my tests, the (surprising, to me) answer is **yes** (I use a `BindingSource` between the DGV and the data).

Here's a snippet from LINQPad and a screenshot to demo:

[image: Sortable data from EF collection. Sorted descending on scan column.]

```
// http://www.csharpbydesign.com/2009/07/linqbugging---using-linqpad-for-winforms-testing.html
void Main()
{
    var context = this;
    using (var form = new Form())
    {
        var dgv = new DataGridView();
        var binder = new BindingSource();
        
        // All of the following variations work
//      var efCollection = context.NOS_MDT_PROJECT;
//      var sortableCollection = new BindingListView<NOS_MDT_PROJECT>(
//          efCollection.ToList());
//      var efCollection = context.NOS_MDT_PROJECT.First()
//          .NOS_DEFL_TEST_SECT;
//      var sortableCollection = new BindingListView<NOS_DEFL_TEST_SECT>(
//          efCollection.ToList());
        var efCollection = 
            from p in context.NOS_MDT_PROJECT
            where p.NMP_ID==365
            from s in p.NOS_GPR_TST_SECT_COMN_DATA
            from l in s.NOS_GPR_TST_LOC_DATA
            select l;
        var sortableCollection = new BindingListView<NOS_GPR_TST_LOC_DATA>(
            efCollection.ToList());
        
        binder.DataSource = sortableCollection;
        dgv.DataSource = binder;
        
        dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        form.Controls.Add(dgv);
        form.Shown += (o, e) => {
            dgv.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
        };
        form.ShowInTaskbar=true;
        form.ShowDialog();
        if (context.IsDirty()) // Extension method
        {
            if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Save changes?", "", 
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2))
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(EDIT: Binding the DGV directly to the `BindingListView` (BLV) seems to work the same as using the `BindingSource` between the DGV and the BLV, so you can just use `dgv.DataSource = efCollection` and still get full databinding.)

I've spent a lot of time researching this question and trying to understand [why you can't just sort an EF collection out-of-the-box](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67c0e261-6bd2-4642-83d5-a99a326f30fc/show-linq-to-entities-results-in-datagridviews-and-able-to-sort) (or any collection, for that matter). Here's a compilation of links to a lot of useful references regarding this question:

### Data binding in general

- [Behind the Scenes: Improvements to Windows Forms Data Binding in the .NET Framework 2.0, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480736.aspx)
- [A Detailed Data Binding Tutorial - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)

### DGV sorting and databinding in general

- [DataGridView Sorting Using Custom BindingList ← CODEcisions](http://www.codecisions.com/datagridview-sorting-using-custom-bindinglist/)
- [c# - How do I implement automatic sorting of DataGridView? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770857/how-do-i-implement-automatic-sorting-of-datagridview)
- [c# - How to sort a DataGridView that is bound to a collection of custom objects? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236109/how-to-sort-a-datagridview-that-is-bound-to-a-collection-of-custom-objects)
- [Implementing a Sortable BindingList Very, Very Quickly - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31418/Implementing-a-Sortable-BindingList-Very-Very-Quic)

### EF specific

- [Quick tips for Entity Framework Databinding - Diego Vega - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2008/10/09/quick-tips-for-entity-framework-databinding.aspx?Redirected=true)
- [Show LINQ to Entities results in DataGridViews and able to Sort](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67c0e261-6bd2-4642-83d5-a99a326f30fc/show-linq-to-entities-results-in-datagridviews-and-able-to-sort)
- [Using the WPF ObservableCollection with EF Entities - Beth Massi - Sharing the goodness - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/05/08/using-the-wpf-observablecollection-with-ef-entities.aspx)

### Master/Detail (a.k.a. Parent/Child) views

- [Master-Detail Data Binding in WPF with Entity Framework - Beth Massi - Sharing the goodness - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/07/14/master-detail-data-binding-in-wpf-with-entity-framework.aspx)
- [Sorting an included collection bound to a listbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/899dc815-e00b-4baf-8b8a-e323e56134c1/sorting-an-included-collection-bound-to-a-listbox)

And if you want the extension method `.IsDirty()`, here it is in VB (needs to be in a Module with the correct Imports statements):

```
''' <summary>
''' Determines whether the specified object context has changes from original DB values.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="objectContext">The object context.</param>
''' <returns>
'''   <c>true</c> if the specified object context is dirty; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
''' </returns>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function IsDirty(ByVal objectContext As ObjectContext) As Boolean
    Return objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
            EntityState.Added Or EntityState.Deleted Or EntityState.Modified).Any()
End Function
```

Comment: Just to save others time, this library doesn't work for me in 2021. Whilst glyphs appear in the DGV, the column sort is shonky.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Andrew Davey, [his blog has many other interesting things.](http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/andrewdavey)

Here a simple use of BindingListView (BLV) in Vb.net that works too:

```
Imports Equin.ApplicationFramework

Dim elements As List(Of projectDAL.Document) = db.Document.Where(
    Function(w)w.IdProject = _activeProject.Id).OrderBy(Function(i) i.Description).ToList

Dim mySource As BindingListView(Of projectDAL.Document)
mySource = New BindingListView(Of projectDAL.Document)(elements)
```