# dgv display list(of T) bottom to top

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `Datagridview` that is bound to a `List(of T)` Is it possible to change the display direction?

Now the display direction is first item at the top of the `dgv` and the last item at the bottom.

Can this be displayed in the reversed direction? I can't seem to find a property for this in the `dgv class`

[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There is no property in `DataGridView` which supports the sorting as you require. But there are other ways to implement sorting in `DataGridView`. See the answers to these questions [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377568/c-sharp-datagridview-sorting-with-generic-list-as-underlying-source),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903196/how-to-sort-winforms-datagridview-bound-to-ef-entitycollectiont/17952576#17952576)

Comment: Sounds like you could just reverse the order of the list.  A language tag would get you more attention.

Comment: I would not like to reverse the order of my list. Because this will change the index of my listed items?