# Sorting rows in DataGridView by clicking on the Header column

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

How to allow sorting rows in the DataGridView by clicking on the Column Header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Could use this in each columns or specified columns to sort the rows`this->dataGridView1->Columns[n]->SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode::Automatic;`

Answer (score 2):

This is an MSDN link that describes the [DataGridViewColumn's SortMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.sortmode.aspx).

But the DataGridView **can't sort any collection automatically** (like `List`). If you want to support sorting and searching on the collection, you have to derive a class from `BindingList` and override a few base class methods and properties.

Comment: It could be very easily achieved with `BindingListView` class, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4217210/2224701

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub GridSupplierHelp_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles GridSupplierHelp.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    GridSupplierHelp.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
End Sub
```

Comment: It is usually better to explain the answer instead of just posting some code.