# Can the DataGridView allow user sort when AutoGenerateColumns is true

Tags: winforms, datagridview

The code I would like to write would look like this:

```
IEnumerable<SomeModel> items = GetTheItems();

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = BuildTheDataSource(items);
```

And the data grid would show the sort glyphs on the headers and allow the user to sort by clicking them.

The most promising lead I've had so far was the SortableBindingList proposed [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217210/644812), but that solution (and others) seem to work only for manually created columns.

**Update**

Well the egg is on my face now! The SortableBindingList does work, but I made a classic blunder:

```
void Bind(List<Model> items)
{
    this.items = new SortableBindingList<Model>(items);

    // oops! "items" is a List<T>... what I really wanted was
    // "this.items" which is a SortableBindingList<T>
    dataGridView1.DataSource = items;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question. The given example of [SortableBindingList](http://www.timvw.be/wp-content/code/csharp/SortableBindingList.zip)

is thus:

```
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        this.ColumnId.DataPropertyName = "Id";
        this.ColumnFirstName.DataPropertyName = "FirstName";
        this.ColumnLastName.DataPropertyName = "LastName";
        this.ColumnBirthday.DataPropertyName = "Birthday";
        this.ColumnScore.DataPropertyName = "Score";

        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        list.Add(new Person(1, "Tim", "4", new DateTime(1980, 4, 30), 100.1));
        list.Add(new Person(2, "Amy", "2", new DateTime(1983, 1, 1), 200.2));
        list.Add(new Person(3, "Sarah", "3", new DateTime(1984, 1, 24), 300.3));
        list.Add(new Person(4, "Mike", "1", new DateTime(1988, 3, 21), 400.4));

        SortableBindingList<Person> persons = new SortableBindingList<Person>(list);

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = persons;
```

so, from the `List<Person>` to `SortableBindingList` the column is created base in the `Fields and Properties` of the `Person`.

what did you mean from your question?:

*but that solution (and others) seem to work only for manually created columns.*

**Update**

Try this one

```
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        IEnumerable<SomeModel> items = GetTheItems();

        SortableBindingList<SomeModel> items = new SortableBindingList<SomeModel>(items.ToList()); 
        dataGridView1.DataSource = items;
```

Comment: I want `AutoGenerateColumns = true` - I don't want to configure the columns in the designer or in code.

Comment: ok.. try this one `SortableBindingList<SomeModel> items = new SortableBindingList<SomeModel>([yourItemList])`;

Comment: i modified my post. i hope it will help and get some idea :)

Comment: Accepted because the way in which your update wouldn't compile pointed me to the bug in my code :)