# Sort direction does not work in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created a datagridview and set the sort mode property of each column to Automatic. I then bind the datagridview with a list, and attempt to sort ascending or descending, but neither is working for my datagridview columns.

My sample code is given below.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PBAttendance
{
    public partial class frmFormTest : Form
    {
        public frmFormTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmFormTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tempDataList tmplist = new tempDataList();
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                tempData tmp = new  tempData();
                tmp.Name=i.ToString();
                tmplist.Add(tmp);
            }


            dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Name";
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = tmplist;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }
    }
    public class tempData
    {
        string name = null;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

    }
    public class tempDataList : List<tempData>
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually "automatic" means you can't change it.

Comment: @banging the up and down arrow in column header doesn't appear while i use the generic list to bind the datagridview. if i use normal list or normally added the content to the cell it is visible and also the information is sorted

Comment: In this case, Automatic sort mean nothing.You have to choose asc or desc, or nothing. Don't add a sort on your dataGrid, and you will be ale to sort it by a click on a column.

Answer (score 0):

By default, List has no support for sorting when bound to a DataGridView (DGV). See [How do I implement automatic sorting of DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770857/how-do-i-implement-automatic-sorting-of-datagridview) for solutions that will work. Mine is to use the [`BindingListView` library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blw/) to make the code as simple as `bs.DataSource = new BindingListView<tempData>(tmplist);`.

Just an additional note on style and syntax, since it looks like you're used to Java and there are some differences:

- Class names are PascalCase (e.g. `TempDataList`, although in the snippet you provided there is no disadvantage to just using `var tmplist = new List<tempData>()`)
- Local variables can be whatever but are usually camelCase (e.g. `tmpList`, although with Visual Studio's intellisense there is no reason to include the type in the name of the variable).
- Sub-classes usually append the name of their base class, e.g. `TestForm` instead of `frmFormTest`, although there are still some advantages to Hungarian notation (`frmTest`) on filenames and classes extending Base Class Libraries. (These advantages don't extend to variable names in most cases, though: it's better to have `bool isFormValidated` than `bool bValid`.)
- Regarding [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), especially [auto-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) with no need for a backing field, just do `public string Name {get; set;}` (the default value for `string`s is `null`). If you want a default value, use a [readonly property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx) (`public string Name {get; private set;}`) and set its value in the constructor or else you can use a backing field.

I don't point these out to be a jerk (and I'm sorry if I've offended); these would have been useful pointers to me a few years ago and maybe others who aren't yet familiar with C# will find them useful. Also, note that [style can be automatically checked](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) (and fixed, e.g. with ReSharper or CodeRush).

Finally, the **best book on .net**, especially for intermediate programmers, is [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) by Cwalina and Abrams (whether or not you are designing a framework).