# Populate DataGridView with a default empty row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I am working on a Windows Application (c#). I have a `DataGridView`, and I am able to bind the data and get the data displayed, everything is good. But I want my `DataGridView` to display a default empty row, even if database does not have data to display. Right now, `DataGridView` is empty when there is no data available. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add a blank row to your data table that you bind to.

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use data-binding for `DataGridView` and bind it to a `BindingSource`, the value of property `AllowUserToAddRows` is true and `DataGridView` always have an empty record at bottom to enable you add new record.

You never need to add an empty record at bottom of a binded DataGridView using other ways.

Here is a tiny sample to create a data list form:

1. Create a Form and put a DataGridView, a BindingNavigator and a BindingSoure ono it
2. Doubleclick on your form and Write code below to Form_Load event:

Code:

```
//example: @".\sqlexpress;initial catalog=YourDatabase;integrated security=True;"
var connection = @"Your Connection String" ;
//example: "SELECT * FROM Category"
var command = "Your Command";
var tableAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command, connection);
var dataTable= new DataTable();
//Get data
tableAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
//Set databindings
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = dataTable;
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;
this.bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = this.bindingSource1;
```

Screenshot:

Look at that empty record at bottom of datagridview.

[image]

Comment: Hi Reza, Thank you very for your reply!! "AllowUserToAddRows" was already set to true, even then the blank row was never displayed. But now, What I did based on "thewisegod" solution is -  DataRow newrow = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.Add(newrow); and It worked. Not sure why AllowUserToAddRows did not work.

Comment: Reza, I did try, it is doing exactly what you said, as soon as i start type in one of the columns in that row, new row is getting displayed at the bottom. For some some reason, not happening in my case. Not sure where I am going wrong. I will need to double check. Also, any quick idea, How do i make columns sortble in the grid view on clicking at column header?

Comment: Good job! When using datatable as your datasource, the columns are sortable by defult. But if you are using List<T> as data source, consider using this [SortableBindingList<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23661356/3110834) instead.

Comment: I had AllowUserToAddRows=true and was getting a mysterious (and in my case undesirable) blank row. Your answer pointed me to the culprit - thanks !