# Using SortableBindingList<T> - DataGridView doesn't automatically sort on changes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

I'm building a Windows Forms Application that displays a custom class `Record` objects and sorts them by how long they've been in my `SortableBindingList<Record>` `record_list`. When I start my program, I have some "dummy" records loaded into this list already for the sake of testing.

The `SortableBindingList<T>` has been taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661195/datagridview-using-sortablebindinglist).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public SortableBindingList<Record> record_list = new SortableBindingList<Record> { };
    public static DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView.DataSource = record_list;
        FillData(); //Temporary function to insert dummy data for demo.
        dataGridView.CellFormatting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.cell_formatting);
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView);
        this.dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        this.dataGridView.Sort(this.dataGridView.Columns["UserName"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);

        start_timer();                 
    }
```

Result before "new" data is added (note: this was alphabetized automatically, specifically entered into the list out of alphabetical order):

[image]

Result after data is added:

[image]

Finally, result after I click the "UserName" header:

[image]

So, must I force a sort every time my DataSource is updated? If that's the case, how do I call a sort in such a manner?

Thank you for your assistance in advance!

Comment: There is no standard `SortableBindingList<T>` class, which one are you referring to?

Comment: It's a customclass taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661195/datagridview-using-sortablebindinglist

Comment: Well, that's why it's not working - it's a pretty basic implementation, typical for SO answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply sort when the list changes.

The [`SortableBindingList<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661356/3110834) needs some changes to keep the the list sorted when some changes made in list. Here is the full code with changes which I made.

Pay attention  The `OnListChanged` method of `BindingList` will be called automatically after adding and removing items. But if you need to `OnListChanged` also runs after changing properties of items, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your model class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
public class SortableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    private bool isSortedValue;
    ListSortDirection sortDirectionValue;
    PropertyDescriptor sortPropertyValue;
    public SortableBindingList() : base() { }
    public SortableBindingList(IList<T> list) : base(list) { }
    protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop,
        ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        Type interfaceType = prop.PropertyType.GetInterface("IComparable");
        if (interfaceType == null && prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
        {
            Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType);
            if (underlyingType != null)
            {
                interfaceType = underlyingType.GetInterface("IComparable");
            }
        }
        if (interfaceType != null)
        {
            sortPropertyValue = prop;
            sortDirectionValue = direction;
            IEnumerable<T> query = base.Items;
            if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                query = query.OrderBy(i => prop.GetValue(i));
            else
                query = query.OrderByDescending(i => prop.GetValue(i));
            int newIndex = 0;
            foreach (object item in query)
            {
                this.Items[newIndex] = (T)item;
                newIndex++;
            }
            isSortedValue = true;
            sorting = true;
            this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
            sorting = false;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot sort by " + prop.Name +
                ". This" + prop.PropertyType.ToString() +
                " does not implement IComparable");
        }
    }
    bool sorting = false;
    protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore
    {
        get { return sortPropertyValue; }
    }
    protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore
    {
        get { return sortDirectionValue; }
    }
    protected override bool SupportsSortingCore
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
    protected override bool IsSortedCore
    {
        get { return isSortedValue; }
    }
    protected override void RemoveSortCore()
    {
        isSortedValue = false;
        sortPropertyValue = null;
    }
    protected override void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!sorting && sortPropertyValue != null)
            ApplySortCore(sortPropertyValue, sortDirectionValue);
        else
            base.OnListChanged(e);
    }
}
```