# How to sort BindingList<T>?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have several thousands MyClass objects stored in `BindingList<MyClass>`. I want to sort them by date property `MyClass.dt`.

Class BindingList doesn't support sorting directly. How I can sort `BindingList<T>` not making duplicate copies of all objects? I need to sort them as in ascending, as in descending order, please.

I don't need special class `SortableBindingList` as described in [BindingList.Sort() to behave like a List.Sort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063917/bindinglistt-sort-to-behave-like-a-listt-sort). I am searching for short solution in one o two lines of code.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't support sorting directly?

Comment: I mean list.Sort() is not possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063917/bindinglistt-sort-to-behave-like-a-listt-sort

Comment: [Using SortableBindingList<T>, DataGridView Doesn't Sort on Changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537273/using-sortablebindinglistt-datagridview-doesnt-sort-on-changes)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Linq would work.

```
var sortedListInstance = new BindingList<MyClass>(unsortedListInstance.OrderBy(x => x.dt).ToList());
```

Keep in mind you get a shallow copy of the sorted list, not duplicate instances of `MyClass`.

*Do not forget to include the namespace at the top of the code file `System.Linq`*

Comment: Note that this is a great solution the first time you are creating the list. When inserting items later, you probably want to make sure that you just [insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132696(v=vs.110).aspx) them at the right index to begin with.

Comment: Will the events I've hooped on to this binding list be gone?

Answer (score 6):

A quick way to implement a Sort on a BindingList is to use the [constructor that takes a backing IList< T >](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132683(v=vs.110).aspx) as its argument.  You can use a `List<T>` as the backing and gain its `Sort` capabilities.

Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132683(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#Anchor_1)

> Use this BindingList to create a BindingList that is backed by list, which ensures that changes to list are reflected in the BindingList.

If your MyClass was defined as:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(string name, Int32 num)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Num = num;
    }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Int32 Num {get; set;}
}
```

then you could do something like this to sort it on the `Num` field.

```
private List<MyClass> backing;
private BindingList<MyClass> bl;

    private void InitializeBindingList()
        {
            backing = new List<MyClass>();
            bl = new BindingList<MyClass>(backing);
            bl.Add(new MyClass("a", 32));
            bl.Add(new MyClass("b", 23));
            bl.Add(new MyClass("c", 11));
            bl.Add(new MyClass("d", 34));
            bl.Add(new MyClass("e", 53));
        }

    private void SortBindingList()
        {
            backing.Sort((MyClass X, MyClass Y) => X.Num.CompareTo(Y.Num));
            // tell the bindinglist to raise a list change event so that 
            // bound controls reflect the new item order
            bl.ResetBindings();
        }
    }
```

You need to call [BindingList.ResetBindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132702(v=vs.110).aspx) method after sorting the backing list to notify any bound controls that the `BindingList` has changed and to update the control.

Comment: The problem with adding items to a backing-list is that `BindingList.ResetBindings` will not add event-handlers for the `PropertyChanged` event for `TItem`. Only the `BindingList(IList<T>)` constructor does that, frustratingly.

Comment: @Dai, I do not understand what you mean.  If I modify the example above to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on MyClass, changes to the underlying items are responded to in a DGV without any additional action required.  Can you provide some more details on your usage case?

Comment: If you call `backing.Add( new MyClass(..) )` instead of `bl.Add( new MyClass(...) )` then property-changed-event handling won't work, even if you call `ResetBindings` after adding them to `backing`.

Comment: @dai, thanks for the clarification, it did not occur to me to return to the original list except for the sorting trick.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Convert it to a data table, then the Automatic will work.
DataGridView.DataSource = ConvertToDataTable(MyList).DefaultView;

public DataTable ConvertToDataTable(IBindingList list)
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   if (list.Count > 0)
   {
      Type typ = list[0].GetType();

      PropertyInfo[] arrProps = typ.GetProperties();

      foreach (PropertyInfo pi in arrProps)
      {

         Type colType = pi.PropertyType;
         if (colType.IsGenericType)
         {
            colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
         }

         dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, colType);
      }

      foreach (object obj in list)
      {
         DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

         foreach (PropertyInfo pi in arrProps)
         {
            if (pi.GetValue(obj, null) == null)
               dr[pi.Name] = DBNull.Value;
            else
               dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(obj, null);
         }

         dt.Rows.Add(dr);
      }
   }
   return dt;
}
```

Comment: Where is the sorting?