# Which bindable/observable .NET Collection<T> or List<T> can be sorted "in situ" , that is, without making a shallow copy?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I would like to two-way bind a collection or list or view of `<customObject>` to the UI, and have this bound "thing" be sortable *in situ*, that is, without making a shallow copy of it, and also raise an event when values change or the order of its items change, so that the UI controls can be notified and respond.

Which .NET classes meet this description?  Please provide the namespaces where they are found.

EDIT: Need to retrofit a legacy WinForms application.

Comment: @dymanoid: Thanks for that info. This is a legacy WinForms app.  I've edited the question.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39714058) in the first marked duplicate for what is probably the most straightforward approach. You can of course use other techniques described, including the "shallow copy" approach that you've already expressed a preference against, or subclassing `BindingList<T>` and implementing an actual in situ sort yourself (quicksort is a well-documented, easy-to-implement option, so that shouldn't be too hard).

Comment: Take a look at [`SortableBindingList`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661356/3110834) with some small [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539248/3110834) to keep it sorted on data changes.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Can the `OrderBy` method be invoked like this?  `MySortable.OrderBy(x=>x.title);` ?

Comment: @Tim no, it cannot. To sort using code, use `ApplySort` method. Also if you bind a `DataGridView` to the sortable binding list, when you click on columns, sort will work as expected.

Comment: Just in case you are using EF, you may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35978408/3110834) useful. It's about filtering however, but I think it may be useful for sort as well.

Comment: @RezaAghaei: Sorry, but I don't understand. That method is not visible from `mySortable` ( nor is ApplySortCore) when I declare the object like this:    `var 
mySortable = new SortableBindingList<myCustomObject>()`.  Am I not using it properly?