# ListBox DataSource Automatic Resetting Doesn't Work With List in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, list, listbox, c++-cli

I have a WinForm project in C++/CLI. I use List as a Datasource of Listbox. I defined myList as Datasource of Listbox in mainForm(void). And in UI when user click button1, program add textbox->text to List. And refresh the ListBox. But ListBox doesn't show any data. After some research, I set Datasource after each click, it works fine. But this complicates the code.

```
public ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MainForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        List1= gcnew List<String^>();
        List2= gcnew List<String^>();

        listBox1->DataSource = List1;
        listBox2->DataSource = List2;

    }
.
.
.
    private: List<String^>^ List1;
    private: List<String^>^ List2;

.
.
.
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
    {
        List1->Add(textBox9->Text);
        List2->Add(textBox11->Text);

        //List1->Sort();
        //List2->Sort();

        listBox1->Refresh();
        listBox2->Refresh();

        textBox9->Clear();
        textBox11->Clear();


    }
```

If i use BindingList it works fine. But I want to use sort method of List type. Why I have to set datasource property of listbox each time? Is there any binding problem? Or memory managing problem? Or is this the normal way to do that?

Comment: A binding list means what it means, it is bindable, a vanilla list isn't. You might be interested in [ApplySortCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.applysortcore?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Also, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712322/how-to-sort-bindinglistt

Comment: Thanks. But i check the datasource value inside Listbox when every list data changed. I saw ListBox->Datasource is updating while list is changing. But it's not showing. And wanna know why.  I already used BindingList in my project.  Purpose of my question, curiosity about programming.

Comment: `DataSource` is a reference value, i.e. your actual list, i.e. `listBox1->DataSource == List1`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Does DataSource changing have no effect?

Comment: `DataSource` is nothing magic, it just holds the reference of the data source you've assigned. Much like in WPF where `DataContext` is the actual object you've assigned, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I find this answer helpful with more details "In Windows Forms, a ListBox or other data-binding-friendly controls display data items using a CurrencyManager. This CurrencyManager monitors the items in the data source and detects changes. However, CurrencyManager may not automatically detect changes in the data source. So when you set the DataSource again, you are actually updating the CurrencyManager and fetching the new data. When we use ways such as BindingList, they automatically detect changes in the data structure and trigger the necessary events."

Answer (score -1):

In Windows Forms, a ListBox or other data-binding-friendly controls display data items using a CurrencyManager. This CurrencyManager monitors the items in the data source and detects changes.

However, CurrencyManager may not automatically detect changes in the data source. So when you set the DataSource again, you are actually updating the CurrencyManager and fetching the new data.

When we use ways such as BindingList, they automatically detect changes in the data structure and trigger the necessary events.