# Resort DataGridView after adding to the bound list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a DataGridView that is bound to a BindingSource that is bound to a BindingList.  I can sort the DataGridView by clicking on a column header, as expected.  But when I drop an item onto the DataGridView, it appears at the bottom of the list rather than in its correct sorted position.  I found code in a StackOverflow grid to check the grid's SortOrder and SortedColumn properties, and if they are set, then to resort the grid.  However, when I put a breakpoint in the DragDrop handler, I find that SortOrder is set to None and SortedColumn is null.

Here's the DragDrop handler:

```
private void dgvCoils_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    int? coilStack = m_draggedCoil.Stack;
    m_currentCharge.RemoveCoil(m_draggedCoil);
    if (coilStack.HasValue)
    {
        DisplayStack(coilStack.Value);
    }
    if (!m_inventoryList.Any(coil => coil.Coil_id == m_draggedCoil.Coil_id))
    {
        m_inventoryList.Add(m_draggedCoil);                
        if (dgvCoils.SortOrder != SortOrder.None && dgvCoils.SortedColumn != null)
        {
            ListSortDirection dir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            if (dgvCoils.SortOrder == SortOrder.Descending) dir = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            dgvCoils.Sort(dgvCoils.SortedColumn, dir);
        }                
    }
}
```

And here is the code where I create the list and bind the source to it:

```
InventorySet coilSet = new InventorySet(m_db);
coilSet.FilterOnField(coilSet.m_archived, 0);
coilSet.Open();
// coilBindingSource.DataSource = coilSet.UnderlyingTable;
while (!coilSet.IsEOF())
{
    m_inventoryList.Add(coilSet.ExportData());
    coilSet.MoveNext();
}
coilBindingSource.DataSource = m_inventoryList;
coilBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
dgvCoils.Refresh();
```

I am not setting any Sort columns in my BindingSource object.  Do I need to?

And do I need to use a BindingSource if the underlying list in a BindingList?

Edit:
In looking back through my source code, I remembered that I had to add code to my ColumnHeaderMouseClick event handler to get sorting to work.  Here is that handler:

```
private void dgvCoils_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    string strColumnName = dgvCoils.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName;
    SortOrder strSortOrder = GetSortOrder(dgvCoils, e.ColumnIndex);

    if (strSortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
    {
        m_inventoryList = new BindingList<InventorySetData>(m_inventoryList.OrderBy(x => typeof(InventorySetData).GetProperty(strColumnName).GetValue(x, null)).ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        m_inventoryList = new BindingList<InventorySetData>(m_inventoryList.OrderByDescending(x => typeof(InventorySetData).GetProperty(strColumnName).GetValue(x, null)).ToList());
    }
    dgvCoils.DataSource = m_inventoryList;
    dgvCoils.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = strSortOrder;
}
```

I am guessing that I am doing too much programmatically, and not letting the DataGridView do what it was designed to do.

Comment: I ended up splitting the code that rebuilds the binding list into a separate method.  The column header event handler stores information about the clicked column in form class member variables and then calls the new method.  The DragDrop event handler adds the dropped item to the binding lest and then also calls the new sorting method.  That works, but I'd love to learn of a better way.

Comment: Take a look at this implementation of [`SortableBindingList<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539248/3110834)