# DataGridView and SortableBindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a sortablebindinglist set as Data source for a datagridview . The items of this list gets updated, added or removed based on the data received from the socket. It updates fine in the datagridview.

```
//At the time of initialization
SortableBindingList<T> SBL = new SortableBindingList<T>(ListFromSocket);
datagridview1.DataSource = SBL;
```

On every update of the list, I add/remove items of the list and then I sort the datagridview. This slows down the UI very much.

```
void UpdateListFromSocket(List<T> newList)
{
    //And on every update of the socket
    foreach(<T> obj in SBL)
    {
        //do some checks
        //update, add or remove items from the list
    }

    datagridview1.Sort(datagridview1.Columns[index], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

As the list grows, the sort of datagridview slows down the UI. I tried to create a SortableBindingList (sorted already) that is a subset of the original SortableBindingList. But when I set this as binding source on update the datagridview starts flickering.

I would like to know the best way to handle this without compromising on performance.

The SortableBindingList that I use is

```
    public class SortableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
    {
        private ArrayList sortedList;
        private bool isSortedValue;

        public SortableBindingList()
        {
        }

        public SortableBindingList(IList<T> list)
        {
            foreach (object o in list)
            {
                this.Add((T)o);
            }
        }

        protected override bool SupportsSortingCore
        {
            get { return true; }
        }


        protected override bool IsSortedCore
        {
            get { return isSortedValue; }
        }

        ListSortDirection sortDirectionValue;
        PropertyDescriptor sortPropertyValue;

        protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop,
            ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            sortedList = new ArrayList();

            Type interfaceType = prop.PropertyType.GetInterface("IComparable");

            if (interfaceType == null && prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType);

                if (underlyingType != null)
                {
                    interfaceType = underlyingType.GetInterface("IComparable");
                }
            }

            if (interfaceType != null)
            {
                sortPropertyValue = prop;
                sortDirectionValue = direction;

                IEnumerable<T> query = base.Items;
                decimal value;
                if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    // check if element count is not 0 and value is decimal
                    if (query.Count() > 0 &&
                        decimal.TryParse(prop.GetValue(query.ElementAt<T>(0)).ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
                    {
                        // convert to decimal and sort
                        query = query.OrderBy(i => Convert.ToDecimal(prop.GetValue(i)));
                    }
                    else query = query.OrderBy(i => prop.GetValue(i));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (query.Count() > 0 &&
                        decimal.TryParse(prop.GetValue(query.ElementAt<T>(0)).ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value))
                    {
                        query = query.OrderByDescending(i => Convert.ToDecimal(prop.GetValue(i)));
                    }
                    else query = query.OrderByDescending(i => prop.GetValue(i));
                }
                int newIndex = 0;
                foreach (object item in query)
                {
                    this.Items[newIndex] = (T)item;
                    newIndex++;
                }
                isSortedValue = true;
                this.OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));

            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot sort by " + prop.Name +
                    ". This" + prop.PropertyType.ToString() +
                    " does not implement IComparable");
            }
        }

        protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore
        {
            get { return sortPropertyValue; }
        }

        protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore
        {
            get { return sortDirectionValue; }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you simply use a DataTable instead of a BindingList (so you don't need any of this anymore and all sorting stuff is performed automatically, by the DataTable's DataView or a BindingSource)?

Comment: I haven't tried DataTable, I thought sortablebindinglist would be simpler and effective. I will give it a try.

Comment: Try [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539248/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei When I tried that implementation, I get an exception when I try to update or remove the list items with an exception saying the list is read-only.

Comment: You can try to suspend the layout while sorting. dgv.SuspendLayout(); do your sort then resume dgv.ResumeLayout();