# Inserting item into SortableBindingList

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a WinForms DataGridView bound to a SortableBindlingList (very similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661356/2212458)).

By default when items are added they will appear at the bottom of the DataGridView.  In the examples I came across where people wanted new items to appear in the correct sorted position they called DataGridView.Sort after adding in the item.

This seems rather expensive to me if you have a large collection of data and items are added frequently.  Does the addition of the following method to SortableBindingList seem like a good idea?  Any ideas on how to make it faster or more robust?

```
public int InsertSorted(T newItem)
{
    PropertyDescriptor prop = sortPropertyValue;
    ListSortDirection direction = sortDirectionValue;
    Type interfaceType = prop.PropertyType.GetInterface("IComparable");

    if (interfaceType == null && prop.PropertyType.IsValueType)
    {
        Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType);

        if (underlyingType != null)
        {
            interfaceType = underlyingType.GetInterface("IComparable");
        }
    }

    if (interfaceType != null)
    {
        IComparable comparer = (IComparable)prop.GetValue(newItem);

        IList<T> query = base.Items;
        int idx = 0;
        if (direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            for (idx = 0; idx < query.Count - 1; idx++)
            {
                if (comparer.CompareTo(prop.GetValue(query[idx])) < 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (idx = 0; idx < query.Count - 1; idx++)
            {
                if (comparer.CompareTo(prop.GetValue(query[idx])) > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        this.InsertItem(idx, newItem);
        return idx;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot sort by " + prop.Name +
            ". This" + prop.PropertyType.ToString() +
            " does not implement IComparable");
    }
}
```

Comment: So the code...works?

Comment: @LarsTech It builds, runs, and items and using this method to add items to the BindingList results in items being added to the DataGridView.  I have not yet done further testing to verify sorting is exactly as expected.