# Windows Forms DataGridView returns not the selected value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

currently I am making first steps with Windows Forms and I have noticed a DataGridView issue what I can't explain by myself. I set the selection mode to whole row and if I click on the row it returns me sometimes not the selected values and shows me still the same values of the preselected row. Is this known, could anyone explain why this happens? Thanks.

Here is my code of the CellContentClick method:f

```
 private void dgvData_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
        if (rowIndex == -1) return;

        string firstName = dgvData.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() ?? "No first name";
        string lastName = dgvData.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString() ?? "No last name";
        string email = dgvData.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString() ?? "No email";

        string d = $"Firstname: {firstName}, Lastname: {lastName}, Email: {email}";

        txtboxPersonData.Text = d;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEx9u.gif)

Comment: Please learn how to use a Debugger, it will make you such a better programmer. Watch a video on YouTube and learn how to set a breakpoint and step through the code F10 and F11. No one will be able to tell you why from the info you've given, we could only guess.

Comment: Don't use `CellContentClick` for this, use e.g., `RowEnter`. Also, you should probably access a Cell as `dgvData["FirstName", e.RowIndex].Value` (i.e., using the Column's Name). You'll find out why sooner or later anyway.

Comment: Thank you Jimi, this is the solution.
I figured out that if I use CellClick and click on the appeared tooltip of the cell the click method does not executes and I run into my issue. But with your solution the method executes also if I click on the tooltip. Perfekt, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), set it's DataSource to a list then assign the BindingSource to the DataGridView.

The list type represents your data, change to match your incoming data.

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

For displaying information in a label on your form add the following readonly property to the class above.

```
public string DisplayInformation =>
    $"Name: {(FirstName ?? "no first" )} {(LastName ?? "no last")} " +
    $"Mail: {(Email ?? "no mail")}";
```

In your form data binding DisplayInformation to a label.

Notes

- if you need sorting see the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661356/5509738).
- If all properties need not be shown, set up columns in the DataGridView to those which need to be displayed followed by `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false` in form load.

Form code

```
public partial class ExampleForm : Form
{
    private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource = new();
    public ExampleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
  
        _bindingSource.DataSource = GetYourDataMethod();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;
 
        DisplayLabel.DataBindings.Add(
            "Text", 
            _bindingSource, 
            nameof(Contact.DisplayInformation));
    }
}
```