# How can I handle this prolbem "DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted."?

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
 using (var context = new NorthwindContext())
            {
                var info = (from p in context.Products
                            join od in context.OrderDetails on p.ProductId equals od.ProductId
                            join c in context.Categories on p.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId
                            join o in context.Orders on od.OrderId equals o.OrderId
                            join e in context.Employees on o.EmployeeId equals e.EmployeeId
                            join cu in context.Customers on o.CustomerId equals cu.CustomerId
                            join s in context.Suppliers on p.SupplierId equals s.SupplierId
                            select new
                            {
                                o.OrderId,
                                cu.ContactName,
                                s.CompanyName,
                                e.FirstName,
                                p.ProductName,
                                c.CategoryName,
                                o.OrderDate,
                                o.Freight,
                            }).ToList();
                dgv.DataSource = info;
                dgv.Refresh();
            }
```

But when I want to sort data by [Freight]:

```
dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns["Freight"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Then I got a problem mentioned in title above. I need your help!

I got a problem mentioned in title above. I need your help!

Answer (score 1):

To provide sorting in the DataGridView, first change the current statement from an anonymous type to a strong type.

**Note** In the code which follows my NorthWind database has different property names so you need to adjust them e.g. `CustomerIdentifier` back to `CustomerId`

Container

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public int OrderId { get; }
    public string CompanyName { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string ProductName { get; }
    public string CategoryName { get; }
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; }
    public decimal? Freight { get; }

    public DataContainer(
        int orderId, 
        string companyName, 
        string firstName, 
        string productName, 
        string categoryName, 
        DateTime? orderDate, 
        decimal? freight)
    {
        OrderId = orderId;
        CompanyName = companyName;
        FirstName = firstName;
        ProductName = productName;
        CategoryName = categoryName;
        OrderDate = orderDate;
        Freight = freight;
    }
}
```

Code to read data

```
public class StackoverflowOperations
{
    public static List<DataContainer> ReadData()
    {
        using (var context = new NorthwindContext())
        {
            return (from p in context.Products
                join od in context.OrderDetails on p.ProductId equals od.ProductId
                join c in context.Categories on p.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId
                join o in context.Orders on od.OrderId equals o.OrderId
                join e in context.Employees on o.EmployeeId equals e.EmployeeId
                join cu in context.Customers on o.CustomerIdentifier equals cu.CustomerIdentifier
                join s in context.Suppliers on p.SupplierId equals s.SupplierId
                select new DataContainer(o.OrderId, cu.CompanyName, e.FirstName, p.ProductName, c.CategoryName,
                    o.OrderDate, o.Freight))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Add the class in [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661356/5509738) to your project.

Form code, one button one DataGridView showing an example for sorting and sorting works by clicking column headers also.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SortableBindingList<DataContainer> _dataContainers;
    private BindingSource _source = new BindingSource();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += OnShown;
    }

    private void OnShown(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dataContainers = new SortableBindingList<DataContainer>(StackoverflowOperations.ReadData());
        _source.DataSource = _dataContainers;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _source;
    }
    private void SortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _source.Sort = "CategoryName DESC";
    }
}
```