# How do I implement automatic sorting of boolean columns in DataGridView using BindingListView?

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, boolean, datasource

I have had a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770857/how-do-i-implement-automatic-sorting-of-datagridview) (DataGridView not automatically sortable when bound to a list, no sorting glyphs in column header cells), and solved it, using the suggested [BindListView](http://blw.sourceforge.net/).
Having a list of objects (e.g. of the class Computer)

```
public class Computer
{  
  public bool isServer { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }  
  ...
}
```

bound to a DataGridView dgv this way, sorting is working for all columns = properties of type string, int or DateTime, but not for **bool** like isSever.
The DataGridView displays bool columns as a clickable DataGridViewCheckBox, which are easier for the user to input compared to a text representation of type string (Y/N or similar), but they are not sorted like the other columns, although I can do this programatically like this:

```
BindingListView<T> view = new BindingListView<T>(this);
dgv.DataSource = view;
dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns[0], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Can the BindingListView provide this functionality for sorting bool columns out of the box (using dll version 1.2.0.0) and I am just missing some (for others) obvious additional steps?
Or is there an (easy) way to extend the functionality by modifying the source code of that library?

I already downloaded the source code from sourceforge.net and also managed to compile it to recreate the dll, but I am not sure where or what to modify to support bool types.

I suspect it to be somewhere in the file AggregateBindingListView.cs, probably in the #region Sorting in class SortCompare, but the complex concepts and code that are used there are a bit above my head (yet), especially the seemingly speed-optimized version of the Compare function using MSIL-Opcodes, DynamicMethods and Delegates.

Any suggestions as to how to make boolean columns sortable as well?
Thanks in advance for anything that helps to shed a bit of light on this problem.