# Sort DataGridView without changing Datasource/BindingList order

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a C# custom `MySortableBindingList : BindingList<MyClass>` 
which implements all stuff for sorting (`SupportsSortingCore, SortPropertyCore, ApplySortCore(...)` etc.), whereby `MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged`

Because of that, I can use this list for a Forms DataGridView (`myDataGridView1.DataSource = mySortableBindingList1`) and sort the DataGridView in my GUI according to the columns/Properties.

**Now the question:** *Can I define how sording the UI `DataGridView` affects the order of the `MySortableBindingList`?*

Because right now, sorting the GridView also sorts the BindingList, but I need to keep the internal (original) order, as I need to access the list using stored indices.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's something to do with your sorting implementation that is causing this.  My suggestion would be to follow [Chris Dogget's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217210/3773066) and download the open source [BindingListView](https://sourceforge.net/projects/blw/?source=typ_redirect).

Usage is simple enough:

```
BindingList<Example> examples = new BindingList<Example>()
{
    new Example() { Foo = "foo1", Bar = "bar2" ),
    new Example() { Foo = "foo2", Bar = "bar4" ),
    new Example() { Foo = "foo3", Bar = "bar1" ),
    new Example() { Foo = "foo4", Bar = "bar3" ),
};

BindingListView blv = new BindingListView(examples);
dataGridView1.DataSource = blv;
```

Sorting is baked in and leaves the underlying list in original order.  Using the previous data, we can iterate through both the source and the `DataGridView` and print out the results to see that they are different. We'll use a `for` loop to demonstrate the indexing you've requested:

```
BindingListView<Example> blv = this.dataGridView1.DataSource as BindingListView<Example>;
BindingList<Example> examples = examples.DataSource as BindingList<Example>;

Console.WriteLine("From BindingListView:");
for (int i = 0; i < examples.Count; i++)
{
    Example ex = examples[i];
    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Foo} {ex.Bar}");
}

Console.WriteLine("\nFrom DataGridView:");

for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i];
    Console.WriteLine($"{row.Cells["Foo"].Value} {row.Cells["Bar"].Value}");
}
```

Output when the `DataGridView` has been sorted by the `Bar` column:

```
/*
From BindingListView:
foo1 bar2
foo2 bar4
foo3 bar1
foo4 bar3

From DataGridView:
foo3 bar1
foo1 bar2
foo4 bar3
foo2 bar4
*/
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this (ok, I expected a 1-2 line sollution and not a 2500 line long project :P) still, the project seems to have quite a lot of extra functions, so I will try. (e.g. does adding items update the UI datagridview/ does the INotifyPropertyChanged work...)

Comment: You should be able to download just the dll's and reference them in your project.  I'd only download the entire `BindingListView` project if I had need to "tinker under the hood".  For your UI updates: use `BindingList<T>` instead of `List<T>`.  I've edited my answer to reflect this change.