# How to sort a Column in DataGridView that is bound to a List in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView in my form and I am binding that DataGridView to a List. 
The column is set to `SortMode=Automatic`.

This is my code

```
List<string> lstLines = new List<string>();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(tbFile.Text);
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  lstLines.Add(line);
}
dgvLines.DataSource = lstLines.Select(x=>new {Text=x}).ToList();
```

When I click on column header I expected the column to be sorted but nothing happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a DataBound column in a DataGridView on a column header click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228340/how-do-i-sort-a-databound-column-in-a-datagridview-on-a-column-header-click)

Comment: Unfortunately it's only that simple when the grid is unbound. What databound, you need to do more work. The typical solution as designed is to implement a sortable IBindingList. See the dupe link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you Can try this......

Complete code to sort the column of datagridview whose datasource is a generic List

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//In the form - In constructor or form load, populate the grid.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    List<student> students;

    private void PopulateList()
    {
        student std1 = new student("sss", 15, "Female");
        student std2 = new student("ddd", 12, "Male");
        student std3 = new student("zzz", 16, "Male");
        student std4 = new student("qqq", 14, "Female");
        student std5 = new student("aaa", 11, "Male");
        student std6 = new student("lll", 13, "Female");

        students = new List<student>();
        students.Add(std1);
        students.Add(std2);
        students.Add(std3);
        students.Add(std4);
        students.Add(std5);
        students.Add(std6);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = students;
    }
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Comparer class to perform sorting based on column name and sort order
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
class StudentComparer : IComparer<Student>
{
    string memberName = string.Empty; // specifies the member name to be sorted
    SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.None; // Specifies the SortOrder.

    /// <summary>
    /// constructor to set the sort column and sort order.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strMemberName"></param>
    /// <param name="sortingOrder"></param>
    public StudentComparer(string strMemberName, SortOrder sortingOrder)
    {
        memberName = strMemberName;
        sortOrder = sortingOrder;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares two Students based on member name and sort order
    /// and return the result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Student1"></param>
    /// <param name="Student2"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int Compare(Student Student1, Student Student2)
    {
        int returnValue = 1;
        switch (memberName)
        {
            case "Name" :
                if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
                {
                    returnValue = Student1.Name.CompareTo(Student2.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    returnValue = Student2.Name.CompareTo(Student1.Name);
                }

                break;
            case "Sex":
                if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
                {
                    returnValue = Student1.Sex.CompareTo(Student2.Sex);
                }
                else
                {
                    returnValue = Student2.Sex.CompareTo(Student1.Sex);
                }
                break;
            default:
                if (sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
                {
                    returnValue = Student1.Name.CompareTo(Student2.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    returnValue = Student2.Name.CompareTo(Student1.StudentId);
                }
                break;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Performing sort on click on Column Header
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the current column details
        string strColumnName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
        SortOrder strSortOrder = getSortOrder(e.ColumnIndex);

        students.Sort(new StudentComparer(strColumnName, strSortOrder));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = students;
        customizeDataGridView();
        dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = strSortOrder;
    }

   /// <summary>
    /// Get the current sort order of the column and return it
    /// set the new SortOrder to the columns.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="columnIndex"></param>
    /// <returns>SortOrder of the current column</returns>
    private SortOrder getSortOrder(int columnIndex)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == SortOrder.None ||
            dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == SortOrder.Descending)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Ascending;
            return SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.Descending;
            return SortOrder.Descending;
        }
    }
```

I am hoping that  it will helps you.....

Comment: Thanks. This SortOrder method is exactly what I needed.I only have simple List so instead of Comparer I simply used this `SortOrder so = getSortOrder(e.ColumnIndex); if (so == SortOrder.Ascending) lstLines.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x, y));
                else if (so == SortOrder.Descending)
                    lstLines.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(y, x));`

Answer (score 1):

A bit refactored code from the answer:

```
class StudentComparer : IComparer<Student>
{
    private readonly string _memberName = string.Empty; // the member name to be sorted
    private readonly SortOrder _sortOrder = SortOrder.None;

    public StudentComparer(string memberName, SortOrder sortingOrder)
    {
        _memberName = memberName;
        _sortOrder = sortingOrder;
    }

    public int Compare(student student1, student student2)
    {
        if (_sortOrder != SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            var tmp = student1;
            student1 = student2;
            student2 = tmp;
        }

        switch (_memberName)
        {
            case "Name":
                return student1.Name.CompareTo(student2.Name);
            case "Sex":
                return student1.Sex.CompareTo(student2.Sex);
            default:
                return student1.Name.CompareTo(student2.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

//

```
private void dgwOrders_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];

    string columnName = column.Name;

    SortOrder sortOrder = column.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection == SortOrder.Ascending
                              ? SortOrder.Descending
                              : SortOrder.Ascending;

    students.Sort(new StudentComparer(columnName, sortOrder));

    dataGridView1.Refresh();

    column.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = sortOrder;
}
```