# How to use SortMode in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to get the sorting to work for the DataGridView.  The sorting should be automatic when I click on the column headers but it is not working.  What am I doing wrong?

```
private void LoadDummyData()
{
    List<AddressBookDummy> list = new List<AddressBookDummy>();
    list.Add(new AddressBookDummy { Name = "Newman, Alfred", Type = "CAR" });
    list.Add(new AddressBookDummy { Name = "Skywalker, Luke", Type = "SUP" });
    list.Add(new AddressBookDummy { Name = "Skywalker, Leia", Type = "BEN" });

    addressBookGrid.DataSource = list;
}

private void InitializeGrid()
{
    addressBookGrid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    addressBookGrid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
    addressBookGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    addressBookGrid.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
    addressBookGrid.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a DataBound column in a DataGridView on a column header click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228340/how-do-i-sort-a-databound-column-in-a-datagridview-on-a-column-header-click)

Comment: Wow, second time this exact question was posted in the last couple hours. There is a search function, people.

Comment: Sorry Charles.  That answer did not come up when I was asking the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to bind to a list that implements sorting, [here's an example](http://www.timvw.be/2007/02/22/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt/)

Summary :

```
public Form1()
{
 InitializeComponent();

 SortableBindingList<person> persons = new SortableBindingList<person>();
 persons.Add(new Person(1, "timvw", new DateTime(1980, 04, 30)));
 persons.Add(new Person(2, "John Doe", DateTime.Now));

 this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
 this.ColumnId.DataPropertyName = "Id";
 this.ColumnName.DataPropertyName = "Name";
 this.ColumnBirthday.DataPropertyName = "Birthday";
 this.dataGridView1.DataSource = persons;
}
```

Comment: Worked great for making my BindingList Sortable.

Comment: Can you please add a summary of the link so that this answer can stand on its own merit without the link? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/189763