# how to sort the datagridview column Got an error : Argument NUll Exception Was Unhandled 

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, gridview-sorting

I am binding the data grid view  by using the following linq to entity framework query  by using the following code..

```
        private void EquipmentFinder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetupCategories();
        productgridview.RowTemplate.Height = 130;
        var products = from prods in axe.product1
                       select new
                       {
                           productid = prods.product_Id,   //0                            
                           productnam =  prods.product_Name, //1
                           productimage = prods.product_Image, //2
                           productprice = prods.product_Price,//3
                           productdescr = prods.product_Description, //4

                       };

        productbindingsource.DataSource = products;
        productgridview.DataSource = productbindingsource;          
        productgridview.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        productgridview.Columns[4].Visible = false;
    }
```

I have got the columns product id , product image ,product name ,product desription,product price..

i have made some of the columns are not visible for the purpose of client ..

now i want to sort the columns by clicking on the column header ....

Note: here the product.image is stored as byte of arrays in database ....

i dont know how to compare the bytes and sorting like that....

would any one pls help on this one......

many thanks...

MODIFIED CODE:

```
          private void productgridview_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
       DataGridViewColumn newcolumn =  productgridview.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) == 1 ? productgridview.SelectedColumns[0] : null;
       DataGridViewColumn oldColumn = productgridview.SortedColumn;
       ListSortDirection direction;

       if (oldColumn != null)
       {
           // Sort the same column again, reversing the SortOrder.
           if (oldColumn == newcolumn &&
               productgridview.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
           {
               direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
           }
           else
           {
               // Sort a new column and remove the old SortGlyph.
               direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
               oldColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
       }


           productgridview.Sort(newcolumn, direction);
           newcolumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection =
               direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ?
               SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;



    }
```

got An error:  Argument NUll Exception Was Unhandled ..

```
           Value cannot be null.
           Parameter name: dataGridViewColumn
```

would any one help on this....

Comment: Didn't get you? the image would be associated with the product and sorted when the product is sorted

Comment: yaa.. i dont know how to sort the column ... if i click on the any column header the entire grid view will be sorted......like that..

Comment: [`Look here`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs.aspx) on how to sort.. and i think its better to sort the images based on the corresponding product and not on the byte array

Comment: If the image is product image they you can sort by product name or if it represents some stautus like out of stock, hot selling etc. then sort based on that column value. usually we disable sorting on Image etc type of columns

Comment: @V4vendetta i am not using any checkboxes and radio buttons for sorting..i want just if i click on the column header the entire  data grdi view will be sorted

Comment: @ TheVillageIdiot would you pls help me with some sample code..

Comment: @V4vendetta see my modified code i have tried that one but got an error

Comment: @ TheVillageIdiot see my modified code i have tried that one but got an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following code and it works, I don't have images so I used empty column. The code is bit long because I had to implement `BindingList<T>` to implement sorting. You can read more about the implementation of `BindingList<T>` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249779/datagridview-sort-and-e-g-bindinglistt-in-net) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/bindinglist_sortable.aspx). You can find more about [`AutoPoco`](http://autopoco.codeplex.com/) [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode58GeneratingDatabaseTestDataWithAutoPocoAndEntityFrameworkCodeFirst.aspx).

```
using AutoPoco.Engine;
using AutoPoco;
using AutoPoco.DataSources;

namespace GridViewSorting
{
    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadGridData();
        }

        private void gv_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var newcolumn = gv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
            var showColumn = newcolumn;

            ListSortDirection direction;
            var sortedColumn = gv.SortedColumn;

            var sd = sortedColumn==null? SortOrder.None:sortedColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection;

            if (sortedColumn == newcolumn && sd == gv.SortOrder)
                return;

            if (sd == SortOrder.Descending || sd == SortOrder.None)
            {
                sd = SortOrder.Ascending;
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            else
            {
                sd = SortOrder.Descending;
                direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            }

            //now the fun begins, suppose this is image column and you want to 
            //sort based on product name when product image column header
            //is clicked.

            if (newcolumn.HeaderText == "ProductImage")//check if image column
            {
                newcolumn = gv.Columns["ProductName"];//sort on product names
            }

            gv.Sort(newcolumn, direction);
            newcolumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
            showColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = sd;//change sort indicator on clicked column
        }

        private void LoadGridData()
        {
            IGenerationSessionFactory factory = AutoPocoContainer.Configure(x =>
            {
                x.Conventions(c => { c.UseDefaultConventions(); });
                x.AddFromAssemblyContainingType<SimpleProduct>();

                x.Include<SimpleProduct>()
                    .Setup(c => c.ProductName).Use<FirstNameSource>()
                    .Setup(c => c.Id).Use<IntegerIdSource>()
                    .Setup(c => c.ProductDescription).Use<RandomStringSource>(5, 20);
            });

            var session = factory.CreateSession();
            var r = new Random(234234);
            var rn = r.Next(5, 100);
            IList<SimpleProduct> products = session.List<SimpleProduct>(25)
                .Impose(x => x.Price, r.Next() * rn)
                .Get();
            var bl = new ProductList();

            foreach (var i in products)
            {
                bl.Add(i);
            }

            gv.DataSource = bl;
        }
    }

    public class ProductList : SortableProductList<SimpleProduct>
    {
        protected override Comparison<SimpleProduct> GetComparer(PropertyDescriptor prop)
        {
            Comparison<SimpleProduct> comparer;
            switch (prop.Name)
            {
                case "Id":
                    comparer = new Comparison<SimpleProduct>(delegate(SimpleProduct x, SimpleProduct y)
                    {
                        if (x != null)
                            if (y != null)
                                return (x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id));
                            else
                                return 1;
                        else if (y != null)
                            return -1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    });
                    break;
                case "ProductName":
                    comparer = new Comparison<SimpleProduct>(delegate(SimpleProduct x, SimpleProduct y)
                    {
                        if (x != null)
                            if (y != null)
                                return (x.ProductName.CompareTo(y.ProductName));
                            else
                                return 1;
                        else if (y != null)
                            return -1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    });
                    break;
                case "ProductDescription":
                    comparer = new Comparison<SimpleProduct>(delegate(SimpleProduct x, SimpleProduct y)
                    {
                        if (x != null)
                            if (y != null)
                                return (x.ProductDescription.CompareTo(y.ProductDescription));
                            else
                                return 1;
                        else if (y != null)
                            return -1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    });
                    break;
                case "Price":
                    comparer = new Comparison<SimpleProduct>(delegate(SimpleProduct x, SimpleProduct y)
                    {
                        if (x != null)
                            if (y != null)
                                return (x.Price.CompareTo(y.Price));
                            else
                                return 1;
                        else if (y != null)
                            return -1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    comparer = new Comparison<SimpleProduct>((x, y) =>
                    {
                        if (x != null && y != null)
                            return x.GetHashCode().CompareTo(y.GetHashCode());
                        return 0;
                    });
                    break;
            }
            return comparer;
        }
    }

    public abstract class SortableProductList<T> : BindingList<T>
    {
        protected override bool SupportsSortingCore{get{return true;}}

        protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.GetInterface("IComparable") == null)return;
            var itemsList = (List<T>)this.Items;

            Comparison<T> comparer = GetComparer(prop);
            itemsList.Sort(comparer);
            if (direction == ListSortDirection.Descending) itemsList.Reverse();
        }

        protected abstract Comparison<T> GetComparer(PropertyDescriptor prop);
    }

    public class SimpleProduct
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string ProductImage { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You will get your thing in `gv_ColumnHeaderMouseClick` function.

Comment: Glad I was of some help. It prompted me to learn something new. that's beauty of SO.